# octopress' categories menu name

Tags: ruby, octopress

I use octopress as my blog engine.Recently when I created C++ categories,but the created menu name is not c++,the "+" was changed to "-", I don't know why?I hope some one could help me.
Thanks very much!

[image: just like this]

Answer (score 0):

Why does this matter?

I also got a category like you, but the category name in blog still shows C++. I think it's OK.

[image]

[image]